# How would I create an activerecord scope(s) that would return customers who's next visit resulted in a purchase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scopes, database-relations

I have three activerecord models: Customer, Visit and Campaign.

```
Customer    has_many   :visits
Visit       belongs_to :customer
Campaign    has_many   :visits
```

The Visit model tracks everytime a particular customer visits a website, pages visited, ads displayed and most importantly if they made a purchase. A Campaign is a series of Ads the customers see during there visits to the site. Each Campaign lasts 1 hour (24 campaigns a day) and has many visits.

What I'm trying to do is develop some activerecord scopes or class methods that will enable me to identify "**Next Visit Purchases**".

For example, on July 4th the fourth campaign of the day had 100 visits by customers. I want to be able to look at the next visit for each of those customers and identify those visits/customers that had/made a purchase on that next visit.  What I'm finding difficult to wrap my mind around is that customers subsequent visits aren't all on the same day, yet I want to identify the "Next Visit" and those that resulted in a Purchase.

What I envisioned is something like:

```
Campaign.find(2232).next_visit.purchase     #where next_visit and purchase are scopes
```

or

```
Visit.find(5445).next_visit.purchase
```

I have a purchase flag in the visits model so the purchase scope is fairly straight forward.

```
scope, :purchase, where(:purchase_flag => true)
```

Also based on the [Railscast #215](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3), if I create this scope on the visits model I can then use joins and merge to apply them to the Customer and Campaign models.

```
Campaign.joins(:visits).merge(Visit.purchase)
```

Is this the correct approach? If so, how do I define my Next scope and if not, what would you suggest as an alternative approach.

**Update**:
I've gotten some great responses.  Just curious to know if the general consensus is that Deepak's approach is on point or are the other responses preferable.

Comment: User2564200 doesn't think scopes are the way to go. Do others agree with that assessment?

Comment: Yes, I also think the same. Please see my suggestion below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is to measure the efficiency of a campaign, and have data about the customers that came back after the campaign and did purchases.

I propose:

```
class Campaign

  def next_visits
    # Wrapping the whole code of this method in @next_visits will perform local caching
    # There is a good railscast that explain it in details (5 minutes long video)
    # You can see it there: http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables
    @next_visits ||= begin
      # This will be the starting date of "next visits"
      since = self.end_of_campaign # I assume you can get the TimeDate of the end of campain

      # List of ids of customers that participated to the campaign
      customers_ids = self.visits.uniq(:customer_id).pluck(:customer_id)

      # Return the visit records
      next_visits = Visit.where(purchase_flag: true, customer_id: customers_ids)
      next_visits.where('created_at > ?', since).first
    end
  end

end
```

Then you call `Campaign.find(123).next_visits`

**EDIT**

You should use correct TZ with the variable `since`

About `@next_visits ||= begin ... end`: This is a caching technique. First time you call the method, all the code inside the `begin` blok will be executed, and the result (the records) will be stored in the instance variable @next_visits and returned to the caller.

Next time you call the method, the cached result stroed in @next_visits will be directly returned without hitting your database. That is good for performance.

More info about that http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you when you say use correct TZ with the variable since. Time Zone?

Comment: Yes Time Zone, I believe the code example I provided will work, but I have no details on how you manage time zone in your application, my edit is just to remind you to apply your conventions in here too

Comment: Edited my example: I just did a little wrap-up in an instance variable to do some local caching

Comment: Benjamin - Your solution makes a lot of sense to me.  Just a couple of question. 1. Does the next_visit.where('created_at > ?', since) need a first. Otherwise would it return all the visits after the campaign instead of the next visit.   2. What does @next_visits ||= begin do. Thanks again. I thought Begin had to be paired with Rescue.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to answer those 2 points, and yes: you could use a rescue block if you want, but its not mandatory. BTW this is Rails 4 code, are you using it or a previous version? Let me know so I would eventually edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

I dont think scope is the right thing here, because you need to call it on an object. You could implement it as a method in visit.rb.

Could be like:

```
def next_visit
  Visit.where(['date > ?', self.date]).order(:date).limit(1).first
end
```

**EDIT:**
For you to be able to chain methods

```
def next_visits
  Visit.where(['date > ?', self.date])
end
```

Comment: So its not possible to have perhaps a third scope that gets it down to a particular Visit and then apply the Next_visit and purchase scope: Visit.number(100).next_visit.purchase  or does it really matter if its a scope or not.  I thought the scope might provide more flexibility and chaining options.  In all cases thanks for the response.

Comment: If you expect `next_visit` to return only 1 visit object, then there is no point in being able to chain methods onto it. In case you want to retrieve multiple `next_visits`, just remove the `.first` call and `limit` from my answer, and you will get an active relation object which will be chainable

Answer (score 1):

In the current database structure it is quite clumsy to achieve what you need and likely be very inefficient as well.

I have a different approach to this problem:

- When a purchase is made - it is best opportunity to know which campaign/visit (check the last visit of the user and find the campaign) led to this purchase.
- To capture these information, create appropriate relationship - with custom name - between campaign and visit.
- Populate these in after_save/after_create callback of appropriate model (most likely Purchase or Visit).

Once the data is captured in above manner, queries are relatively easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just want to clarify what you are proposing.  So are suggesting a new Model that captures campaigns an purchases or simply an associations.

Comment: Just an association between a Visit and a Campaign should suffice. You will have to use a custom name as you already have a relation between campaign and visit.

Comment: Alternatively you can create association between Campaign and Purchase (if you have a model for that). It depends on your requirement.